# How to identify if your device supports LTE-Advanced?

Tags: android, gsm, cellular-network, lte, 4g

Not all 4G devices support LTE-A, and manufacturers usually don't give clear information if it is supported by your model, hence I want to know if there is any way to test this.

Thanks.

For those who are new:

*The LTE-Advanced is an extension of regular LTE, it uses 'Carrier Aggregation' technology & multiple antennas on both BTS & Mobile devices to pump in more data per instance, allowing at least 3 times faster LTE speeds.
Top networks around the world are testing / deploying LTE-A in major cities, with speeds crossing 42 Mbps in real scenarios.*

Comment: How are you trying to identify LTE-A support? Programmatically, from L3 signaling or other?

Comment: I have a Wi-Fi 4G Router by Reliance Jio. The carrier is currently rolling out LTE-A & carrier aggregation technologies in many places, but I have no idea if my 4G router supports. There exists a web interface to access router's network info, it shows the band used (3, 5 or 40), or network info like Global CID, ECGI, RSRP etc. There is no mention of MIMO or LTE-A. Hence wanted to know, if there is any way to identify support. The manufacturer's box mentions LTE (3,5,40) but nothing on LTE-A. As for identification, any means will do, be it programmatically or other, that the community suggests.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the model # and a screenshot of what you see under Settings -> LTE

Comment: Questions about topics other than development or programming, but related to Android, are not on-topic for Stack Overflow, but **may** be on-topic at https://android.stackexchange.com (and you're more likely to get a good answer there). Please review [the guidelines for posting in that community](//android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there to ensure that your question is on-topic.